# solving integral in simpson quadrature method in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to find an integral

```
b = ((8*WL* Requ)/(pie* WC *Eequ))^.5 

z = quad( 'exp(sqrt(1-((x.^2)./b^2) ))',-b,b)
```

I used Simpson quadrature (quad) built in command for this. I got the right results but my problem is that, I want quad command to pick up automatically the changing values of (b) from the formula of (b) written in my code. But it didn't do that. I have to put in each changing value of (b) into function.

Comment: Can you make your question more explicit and show a simple example of your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[quad](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/techdoc/ref/quad.html) is aimed at numerical integration. In your posted code the integrand is written as symbolic expression (string).

```
b = ((8*WL* Requ)/(pie* WC *Eequ))^.5;

F =  @(x)exp(sqrt(1-((x.^2)./b^2) );
z = quad( F, -b, b);
```